# How to make references appear on a new page?

Tags: bibliographies, article

I am using the  `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` and I want to insert images on full width. For that I am using:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{artworks/pearson-single-dendrogram.png}
\caption{Single Linkage Agglomerative Clustering}
\label{single-linkage-dendrogram}
\end{figure}
```

But if I print the bibgliography underneath afterwards using `\newpage \printbibliography` . it appears on top of the figures, rather than from the new page. Does anyone know how this can be fixed?[image]

Comment: For images, that you want to insert across both columns of text, use `figure*` instead of `figure`.

Comment: full width spanning figures are `{figure*}` not `{figure}`

Comment: Great, thank you! I fixed it.

Comment: This is slightly different, because this article class needs a different approach.